# Get items based on object ID (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get specific items from the database based on the ID which is referenced on the sub-object.

I have a Shoutout table, and each shoutout consist of multiple Hashtags.
So i have this so far:

```
public function shoutoutSpecific($hashtag) {
    $hashtags = Hashtag::whereHashtag($hashtag)->get();
    $shoutouts = '';


    return view('shoutout', compact('shoutouts'));
}
```

But this only gives me the hashtags, where each hashtag references to the specific shoutout. And i need to get the shoutout, which the hashtag is referencing to by ID.

But I was wondering if there is a way to get the shoutouts, where the shoutouts have a specific hashtag referenced to them.
Something like:

```
Shoutouts = Shoutout::whereHashtag-referenced($hashtag)->get();
```

Comment: Is a `shoutout` a standard piece of Laravel? If not how are we supposed to be of any help when you describe your issue so badly. Remember we **are not clairvoyant** and we **are not looking over your shoulder**

Comment: Well, someone did though... But thanks for taking your time to check out my problem anyways :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Shoutout` class has the `hasMany` relation as:

Shoutout.php

```
public function hashtags()
{
    return $this->hasMany(App\Hashtag::class);
}
```

Then you can try as:

```
Shoutouts = Shoutout::whereHas('hashtags', function($q) use($hashtag) {
    $q->whereHashtag($hashtag);
})->get();
```

Comment: Definetly! I can do it in 2 min, as it gives me the "You cant accept within..." :)